# Tesseract OCR for nepali/hindi

Tags: windows, ocr, tesseract

I have two questions:
1)
I am very new to tesseract OCR. I am trying to detect Nepali language using this engine. I downloaded Nepali OCR from "**http://nepalinux.org/index.phpoption=com_content&task=view&id=46&Itemid=53**"
But I don't know how to use this with Windows. So I need a help for this

2)
For trying this engine, I tried with hindi language which is in very ways similar to nepali language. In command promt when i entered "**tesseract image outputfile -l hin**" it says **tesseract.exe has stopped working** while it works perfectly for english language. Why am I facing this problem??

Comment: I recommend compiling it on Linux and then copying `nep.tessdata` to your Windows installation. As for crash, it's simply a bug of some sort.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If it is possible, can you elaborate this in more detail. As i am very new to linux and tesseract. Thank you